# Django testing - NoReverseMatch

Tags: django

Why is this test does not work?

This is my views.py:

```
class ObjectDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = "object-detail.html"
    model = Object
    slug_field = 'username'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ....
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^object/details/(?P<slug>[-\w.]+)/$', ObjectDetailView.as_view(), name='object-details'),
```

tests.py:

```
class ObjectViewsTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['/app/fixtures/object_fixture.json', ]

    def test_object_details(self):
        user = User.objects.get(id=1)
        self.client.login(username=user.username, password=user.password)
        resp = self.client.get(reverse('object-details', kwargs={'slug': user.username}))
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

My error:

> NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'object-details' with arguments '()' and
>   keyword arguments '{'slug': u'admin'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried:
>   []

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a [`ROOT_URLCONF`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#root-urlconf) in your settings ? If so, make sure that when you run the tests these settings are loaded. Or you can add the following in your tests :

```
class ObjectViewsTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['/app/fixtures/object_fixture.json', ]
    urls = 'path.to.your.urls'  # for instance 'base.app.urls'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with update and delete views. It seems to me that you need to pass the PK on the request... like so:

```
    def test_service_delete_view(self):
        w = self.create_service()
        response = self.client.get(reverse('services:service-delete', kwargs={'pk': w.pk}))
        self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
```